# Bouncy castle java - Triple DES cryptography is symetric or asymmetric?

Tags: cryptography, bouncycastle, encryption-asymmetric

Bouncy castle java - Triple DES cryptography is symemtric or asymmetric?

I am using bouncy castle Java API for implementing tripleDES, but I do not know if it is symmetric or asymmetric key cryptography.

Can somebody help me to answer this question.

Comment: Don't be so hasty to delete questions (I rather liked the last one). Give them time to get some good replies. SO is a global community and people (with different levels/specializations of knowledge and experience) come and go.

Comment: That said, if you don't know if you are using symmetric or asymmetric encryption, you might want to read into the subject matter, because you are going to implement it badly (e.g. forgetting integrity checks on the encrypted data). Strangely, the wikipedia article only mentions that it is symmetric on the 
DES page, not on the triple-DES page.

Answer (score 2):

Triple DES is an symmetric block cipher, a rather old one. I would stick to stronger algorithms (e.g. AES) if I had the choice.